# Slowdown in Apache with HTTP/2 when Requesting Small Thumbnails (60KB) via Reverse Proxy to HTTP/1.1 Backend

Tags: web-server, performance, apache2, http2

I am currently running an Apache server with HTTP/2 enabled as a reverse proxy for my web application. I have noticed a significant slowdown when requesting a large number of small thumbnails (each approximately 60KB) through this configuration. Strangely, this slowdown started to occur after switching from HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2, even though HTTP/2 is supposed to improve performance(especially in this case, as requesting many small files is a great use case for all the fancy multiplexing stuff HTTP/2 does).

- When requesting images sequentially I haven't noticed a slowdown, but only when the client files a lot of files at once (about 200).
- The bakend only talks HTTP/1.1 and is accessible using the reverse proxy. The thumbnails are precached on the disk.

Here is Chromium's waterfall graph for HTTP/2:
[Waterfall HTTP/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZVwG.png)

And for HTTP/1.1:
[Waterfall HTTP 1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91WT0.png)

As you can see in the images the HTTP/2 requests are no longer stalling, but the overall time increased.

Any pointers or Tips how to further debug this would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This should be a comment - but space limited)

1.) The first place to look when a service is not behaving as expected is in the logs. But the default log formats do not capture useful timing information - you should add at least %D on httpd

2.) I love Apache httpd as an origin server, but it's a less than ideal as a reverse proxy

3.) When asking for help about software not working as intended it is a good idea to provide the version information and the details of how it is configured

4.) What you've shown us looks more like something conforming to HTTP/1.1's limit on concurrent requests than something slowing down (but I've not seen this behaviour from mod_proxy)

Comment: Well, I've followed your advice and debugged Apache timings. Turned out apache tried to keep (dead?) connections with my Backend Server alive. Dropping the communication with the backed server to HTTP/1.0 with "SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1" increased the speeds back to normal again. Do you have any clue why ? Furthermore I followed your advice and switched to nginx as proxy for my Backend (but with no further easily measureble speed improvement compared to apache with dropped backend protocol ) Can you give me references why nginx is the better option? Nethertheless thanks a lot.

Comment: There's lots of references on the internet. Bit there's also a lot of misinformation out there. Under light load, Apache will outperform nginx. under heavy load the other way around. But the advantage of nginx as a *reverse proxy" is that its memory footprint does not increase nearly as fast as Apache's as the number of connections increases.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is to do with a combination of hitting the maximum Apache session stream limit, with how off-screen images (and other lower priority requests) are handled by Chrome in HTTP/2 and above, when that happens.

By default [mod_http2 allows a maximum of 100 streams](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_http2.html#h2maxsessionstreams) at any one time. After this, requests will be queued before being sent.

I have a similar test here (though with smaller images): https://https.tunetheweb.com/performance-test-360/

When testing under a 4g connection:

- On mobile (where most of the images are off screen) you see this stair step effect on HTTP/2 after 100 images, and Chrome waits for all the currently inflight requests to be finished before it sends of the next set in batches of 8: https://www.webpagetest.org/result/231001_BiDcVS_6JG/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1
- On Desktop (where all of the images are on screen) there is still a delay in sending images 100+ on (as it can't as the maximum stream limit has been reached), but Chrome does not wait for ALL the current in-flight images to be drained before starting: https://www.webpagetest.org/result/231001_BiDcT3_6SC/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1

Doing the same tests under HTTP/1.1 you don't see this stair step effect:

- Mobile: https://www.webpagetest.org/result/231001_AiDcTM_6YH/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1
- Desktop: https://www.webpagetest.org/result/231001_AiDcAF_6XZ/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1

However, HTTP/2 is considerably faster than HTTP/1.1 in both those tests (9.775 seconds versus 13.864 seconds on mobile, and 4.129 seconds versus 13.622 seconds on desktop). It's possible with larger images this trade off may not work as well and HTTP/2 may end up being slower.

So I'd suggest repeating your tests with all the images being on-screen. Or alternatively upping the `H2MaxSessionStreams` maximum size to one better suited for your site.

Rerunning the mobile test after capping `H2MaxSessionStreams` to 400 shows it doesn't limit it: https://www.webpagetest.org/result/231001_BiDcBW_70Q/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1

However, when many requests are inflight at once you end up hitting all sorts of prioritisation issues. Should servers send a little of each response in a round robin fashion? Or send the first responses in full in order they were requested. Much has been written about this (see [this post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/better-http-2-prioritization-for-a-faster-web/) for example) and the answer depends on many things. For HTML and images (and in particular progressive images) sending bits at a time can be better as they can be processed by the browser as they arrive. For other resources where the whole resources is needed before it can be used (think CSS and JavaScript) sending pieces is not useful and you'd be better sending the responses in order.

So I'd caution in changing the defaults too much here as may not actually be that helpful. Plus is will require more resources on the browser and the server. If this is due to off screen images this may not be as bad as your testing shows as impact to the user may be much smaller.

I'd also advise trying to reduce the numbers of resources on your page. 200+ files is a LOT to handle. HTTP/2 makes requests cheaper, but not free.